# AFNetworking JSON Request, neither success nor error block called

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary, afnetworking

I'm trying to learn AFNetworking so have written a simple block. I'm trying to retrieve & log the json from the site url below.

```
NSString *string =
@"http://transportapi.com/v3/uk/bus/stop/490012745J/live.json?api_key=6ee115459cbeccdb902b14d39b61330d&app_id=9deefeb1&group=route";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSDictionary *mydict = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

     NSString *key;
     for(key in mydict){
         NSLog(@" key %@", key);
     }

 }
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                     NSLog(@"ERROR");
                                 }];
```

But neither the success or the failure block is being called. Can someone point out what I've done wrong?

Comment: I guess your operation is released, you should retain it when request hasn't finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually firing the operation you need to add

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];
```

Comment: Thank you Flexicoder (and oldman). Have changed my code, failure block being called. Any reason why the success one isn't?

Comment: You need to look at the contents of `error`, it should give you the reason

Comment: Yup, responseSerializer was receiving the incorrect content type. Have changed it, and it works now. Thank you.